# Forward email from Google Apps to Postfix and pipe them to PHP Script

Tags: php, postfix, g-suite

Can somebody throw me in the right direction in order to get emails forwarded from Google Apps to be piped by Postfix to a PHP Script? This answer didn't helped much but to tell me that I need to confgiure a subdomain in order to receive the email and pipe them to a php script. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a MX record pointing at the postfix server, for example:

host.example.com IN MX postfixserver.example.com

Then you can set up [forwarding](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10957) to forward to address@host.example.com where address is the alias on the postfix server that's piping to the script.

Also, be aware, only system aliases in /etc/aliases can be piped to scripts in Postfix, virtual aliases can't be setup to use a pipe.